# Secure Property Placeholder in Mule

Tags: mule

In order to implement Mule Credentials Vault, I downloaded Mule Property Editor and Secure Property Placeholder plugins from 
http://security-update-site.s3.amazonaws.com/

I'm using Mule Studio 3.5.0 but still I can't find Secure Property Placeholder in the global mule configuration element list.

Can someone advise how to include it in the list or any other checks

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please install "Anypoint Enterprise Security".

Details available in the link:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Installing+Anypoint+Enterprise+Security

Answer (score 0):

In the XML view, it should be available via content-assist(ctrl+space): secure-property-placeholder:config

Or via the graphical view: Global Elements > Create > Connector Configuration > Secure Property Placeholder

Comment: Tried both ways, not visible

Comment: Plugin says Mule 3.5.0+ so I expect it work with 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mule 3.5.x, you'll need to install an older version of Anypoint Enterprise Security.

Specifically, when you set up your update site under **Install New Software...**, use the url:
http://security-update-site-1.3.s3.amazonaws.com

See http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/35X/Installing+Anypoint+Enterprise+Security for full details. (Note the "35X" in the URL, which takes you to the 3.5.x version of the documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

Try updated link for site

Anypoint Enterprise Security
http://security-update-site-1.4.s3.amazonaws.com

reference:http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Installing+Anypoint+Enterprise+Security

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, Go to help->install new software->clock on add and then give name as a Anypoint Enterprise Security and Location as a http://security-update-site-1.5.s3.amazonaws.com, you have to select all the check boxes and install it. restart the mule if it asks and then you will be able to find Mule properties editor.

For reference : http://blogs.perficient.com/integrate/2016/05/16/mule-enterprise-security-password-encryption-steps/